# Jquery onclick event Load specific node(s) of XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, parsing, onclick

I need to find a way to pass the correct input to this javascript function to have it search an XML document and return the requested node value(s).  The parsing of the XML node values actually does work properly when hard-coded as seen below and I can successfully load content using the following:

```
    function parse(document){

    Lyrics2 = $(document).find('elementRef[id="2"] content').text()
    Ref2 = $(document).find('elementRef[id="2"] bibleRefs').text() 
    $("#content").text(Lyrics2);
    $("#scripture").text(Ref2);
    };

$.ajax({
url: 'songlyrics.xml',
dataType: "xml",
success: parse
});
```

The problem is I want to pass an additional parameter to the parse function that searches for somnething else in the XML.  The ultimate goal is to have a div updated on the page with modified content from the XML document once a link is clicked, for example, something like this (where 'reference' is the search string passed in):

```
    function parse(document,reference){

    Lyrics2 = $(document).find(reference).text()
    $("#content").text(Lyrics2);    
 };

...
<div id="content"></div>
<a href="javascript:;" id="play" onclick="javascript:parse(document,'elementRef[id=\&quot;2\&quot;] artist')">Title</a>
```

What is happening is the text that is present on page load is replaced with nothing after clicking a link that has onClick specified to run the 'parse' function--no errors are generated in the debug window.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <elements>
           <elementRef id="1">
              <name>John</name>
              <artist>Smith</artist>
              <content>Active</content>
              <supportImg>test1</supportImg>
              <bibleRefs>Mark 2:13</bibleRefs>
              <other>Mark 2:11</other>
           </elementRef>
           <elementRef id="2">
              <name>Jane</name>
              <artist>Smith</artist>
              <content>Active</content>
              <supportImg>test2</supportImg>
              <bibleRefs>John 3:17 Mark 12:3</bibleRefs>
              <other>October, 2011</other>
           </elementRef>
 </elements>
```

Please let me know if you need more information in order to help.  Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is

```
function parse(reference) {
    if (!xml) { //the ajax request is not yet loaded so there is nothing to do
        return;
    }
    var content = $(xml).find(reference).text()
    $("#content").text(content);
};

var xml;
$.ajax({
    url: '
    songlyrics.xml ',
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (doc) {
        //assign the loaded xml content to a gloabl variable so that it can be used later
        xml = doc;
    }
});
```

then

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="play" onclick="javascript:parse('elementRef[id=\&quot;2\&quot;] artist')">Title</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this when I get home! Really appreciate it Arun!!